# Using variables in updateMany query to update certain fields with constraints in MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, nosql

Given I have a MongoDB that roughly corresponds to the following scheme:

```
[
  {
    xzy123: [
      {
        a: [
          1,
          2,
          null,
          4,
          5
        ],
        b: [
          0,
          2,
          2,
          5,
          5
        ]
      }
    ],
    xxz345: [
      {
        a: [
          1,
          2,
          3,
          4,
          5
        ],
        b: [
          null,
          2,
          2,
          null,
          5
        ]
      }
    ],
    fun412: [
      {
        a: [
          1,
          2,
          3,
          null,
          5
        ],
        b: [
          null,
          2,
          0,
          null,
          5
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I'm looking for a query that would update the numeric value in b depending on the value in a.

More explicitly, I want to update the value in b to be 0 given that the value of the same index in a is not null or 0, but only for indexes that are >1:
For example, xxz345.b.3 should be set to '0', as the value in xxz345.a.3 is not null and > 0, fun412.b.3 must n9ot be changed, as fun412.a.3 is null. Also fun412.b.0 does not need to be changed, since the index 0 is smaller than 2.

So far this is the query that I've come up with. It runs, but doesn't update any documents in the collection.

```
db.collection.updateMany(
{
  $and: [
    {"$[elem].a.$[i]": {$gt: 0}},
    {"$[elem].b.$[i]": null}
    ]
  },
  {
    $set: {"$[elem].b.$[i]": 0}
  },
  {
    arrayFilters: [
      {
        "elem": {$exists: true}
      },
        {"i": {$gt: 0}
      },
    ]
  })
```

Any hints that point me in the right direction are as much appreciated as actual solutions.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand how you like to update the values and your data design is rather complex. Dynamic field names are always bad and I am not sure if `xzy123`, `xxz345`, etc. really need to be an array.

Anyway, an approach could be this one:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
   { $project: { data: { $objectToArray: "$$ROOT" } } }, // transform to {k: ..., v: ...} array
   {
      $set: { 
         data: {
            $filter: { // remove `_id` field
               input: "$data",
               cond: { $ne: ["$$this.k", "_id"] }
            }
         }
      }
   },
   {
      $set: {
         data: {
            $map: {
               input: "$data",
               as: "item",
               in: {
                  k: "$$item.k",
                  v: {
                     $map: {
                        input: "$$item.v",
                        as: "ab", // -> { a: [ 1, 2, null, 4, 5 ], b: [ 0, 2, 2, 5, 5 ] }
                        in: {
                           a: "$$ab.a",
                           b: {
                              $map: {
                                 input: { $range: [0, { $size: "$$ab.b" }, 1] },
                                 as: "i",
                                 in: {
                                    $let: {
                                       vars: {
                                          a: { $arrayElemAt: ["$$ab.a", "$$i"] },
                                          b: { $arrayElemAt: ["$$ab.b", "$$i"] }
                                       },
                                       in: {
                                          $cond: {
                                             if: { $eq: ["$$a", null] }, // -> put conditions here based on "$$a", "$$b" and "$$i"
                                             then: "new 'b'", // -> here put desired value for "b"
                                             else: "$$b"
                                          }
                                       }
                                    }
                                 }
                              }
                           }
                        }
                     }
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }
   },
   { $replaceWith: { $arrayToObject: "$data" } } // transform back from {k: ..., v: ...} array
])
```

If you want to update existing data, then replace `db.collection.aggregate([` by `db.collection.updateMany({}, [`